# Ошибка при синхронизации проекта на GItHub

Tags: git, android-studio, github

При создании коммита выдает такую ошибку:

> Some files contain problems.
> No errors and 3 warnings found.
> Would you like to review them?

Если нажать "Commit", все изменения успешно зальются.

В чем тут проблема и как её исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не проблема github или даже git. Просто Android Studio нашла проблемы в Вашем коде и спрашивает, действительно ли такое нужно коммитить. Нажмите Review, посмотрите, что там и исправьте.

Comment: Анализ кода: Некоторые файлы содержат проблемы. Найдено три предупреждения и ни одной ошибки. Хотите ознакомиться с ними? Кнопки: Посмотреть, Все равно закомитить с ошибками, Отменить. В общем анализор кода Lint нашел какие то замечания по вашему коду, например хардкорные строки или другое. Если вы считаете, что все нормально, можете смело коммитить, но к предложениям анализатора желательно прислушиваться